# Osmbonuspack - osmdroid - mapsforge - library dependency issues

Tags: android, osmdroid

For android I use mapsforge tiles via osmdroid and osmbonuspack. 
Till now I used the following software

- osmbonuspack
- omsdroid
- mapsforge-map (dependencies).
- The Salida software solution, as shown via http://www.salidasoftware.com/how-to-render-mapsforge-tiles-in-osmdroid

**Question1**: Is it still requested to use the Salida solution? Or is the newer osmdroid-mapsforge library 5.x sufficient?

**Question2**: I am trying to get the 5.9 version working, but I cannot succceed in doing that. 
What are the dependencies I have to use in Grade?

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" };
    mavenCentral();
}

dependencies { 
    ... 
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:5.2';
    compile 'com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:5.9';
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android-5.4.1-release.aar';
}
```

When I use this, I keep on getting errors that the osmdroid-android-5.4.1-release.aar on jcenter.bintray.com is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question1: Is it still requested to use the Salida solution? Or is the newer osmdroid-mapsforge library 5.x sufficient?

The salida solution looks a lot like what what osmbonuspack did originally that was eventually updated and migrated into the osmdroid-mapsforge library.

> Question2: I am trying to get the 5.9 version working, but I cannot succceed in doing that. What are the dependencies I have to use in Grade?

Looks like you're mixing up dependency versions

try this

`dependencies { 
    ... 
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:5.5:release@aar';
    compile 'com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:5.9';
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.5:release@aar';
}`

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice [demo app](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/tree/master/osmdroid-forge-app) based on the new libraries. It also works on (offline) **MAPSFORGE** maps!!

So, the original Salida software is not needed any more. Just use the osmdroid-mapsforge library.

It is important to add the following dependencies as well:

```
compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-core:0.6.1'
compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map:0.6.1'
compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android:0.6.1'
```